# Matlab using string and floats for 2d graph

Tags: matlab

Currently i have a function which plots the data in a graph as following:

```
function [ dim ] = showg( varargin )
%SHOWG Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

linespec = {'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'};
figure
hold on
filter_size = 1000;
a=1;
b = (1/filter_size)*ones(1,filter_size);

x=1;
y=0;
while x<=nargin

ch = cell2mat(varargin(x+1));
input = cell2mat(varargin(x));    
    %ch = CInt(varargin(x+1))
    %input = varargin(x)
    dim = size(input);

    for i = 2:(ch+1)
        z=i+y-1;
        color = mod(z,7);
        if color == 0
            color = 7;
        end
        out = (input(51:dim(1),1)-input(51,1))/1000;
        out2 = filter(b,a,input(51:dim(1),i));
        size(out)
        size(out2)
        plot(out',out2,linespec{color});
        legendInfo{z} = ['ch' num2str(z)];
    end
    y=(i-1);


    x=x+2;

end
legend(legendInfo);
xlabel('Time in s');
ylabel('Energy in J');

title('new plot')

   hold off; 
return 
end
```

However The lines currnetly generated give the name ch1,ch2 etc. I want to change that dynamically from the same file the data is coming from. A small snippet from the data is here which is a .csv important via matlab:

```
;Chipset;HDD;CPU1;MEM1;
43445653;0.01;0.01;0.01;0.00;
43445654;0.02;0.01;0.01;0.01;
43445655;0.03;0.02;0.02;0.01;
43445656;0.04;0.02;0.03;0.02;
```

Im importing this all with a Matrix however i can't figure out how to use the strings "Chipset, HDD" etc for the names instead of ch1, ch2.

Comment: what is your variable `ch`?

Comment: can you give us a working example, meaning, how would you call your function?

Comment: @SamuelNLP I would call the function within matlab as following: showg(COM8UD25,4). COM8UD25 being the full data from the csv file (currently without the names chipset,hdd etc).

Comment: how are you importing the data?

Comment: @SamuelNLP currently within matlab itself under Import data -> select the colums -> Matrix. All still without the names yet. I want to somehow include the names so this can be seperated and done at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just import your data in a cellarray with text for field, as in the below image,

[image]

and you will end up with:

```
>> file

file = 

    ''            'Chipset'    'HDD'     'CPU1'    'MEM1'
    '43445653'    '0.01'       '0.01'    '0.01'    '0.00'
    '43445654'    '0.02'       '0.01'    '0.01'    '0.01'
    '43445655'    '0.03'       '0.02'    '0.02'    '0.01'
    '43445656'    '0.04'       '0.02'    '0.03'    '0.02'
```

then extract your labels for the legend:

```
>> legends = file(1,2:end)

legends = 

    'Chipset'    'HDD'    'CPU1'    'MEM1'
```

Then you can get your data by,

```
>> data = file(2:end, :)

data = 

    '43445653'    '0.01'    '0.01'    '0.01'    '0.00'
    '43445654'    '0.02'    '0.01'    '0.01'    '0.01'
    '43445655'    '0.03'    '0.02'    '0.02'    '0.01'
    '43445656'    '0.04'    '0.02'    '0.03'    '0.02'
```

which can be turned into a matrix of doubles by,

```
>> data = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,data,'un',0))

data =

    43445653    0,01    0,01    0,01    0
    43445654    0,02    0,01    0,01    0,01
    43445655    0,03    0,02    0,02    0,01
    43445656    0,04    0,02    0,03    0,02
```

well, you can work from here...

OK, I've imported my data and called `showg(file)`,

your `varargin` will be a `1x1cell`, so just do `newfile = varargin{1}`.

Example of your function

```
function [ dim ] = showg( varargin )
%SHOWG Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

%% MYCODE
newfile = varargin{1};
legends = newfile(1,2:end);
data = newfile(2:end, :);
data = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,data,'un',0));

%% go from here...
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately i just have problems importing the data  in a cellarray as it marks the Chipset and HDD as wrong which will be replaced for NaN. I can't seem to find a way to put this as text.

Comment: The only problem i am facing is that you turn it into a matrix when you just have the data without the text. However i import it via varargin which makes everything a 1x1 cell like {8x5 cell} (including the text) so i can't extract the labels off it like you show me.

Comment: do you call your function by `[ dim ] = showg('file.csv')`??

Comment: No, as explained before i import it via Import data -> Select .csv file -> Select coloms -> Cell array. Then via showg(COM8UD25,4) i call the function. COM8UD25 is the data. I seperate both so that varargin holds just COM8UD25 data but combined into a 1x1 cell: varargin      1x1               512  cell which holds {8x5 cell} (that is the actual data) not as you showed before the "File".

Comment: I've altered my answer again and added the new start for your function.

Comment: Hi! I've made a MATLAB chat room for us in case you wanted to discuss anything related to MATLAB that is off-topic, or if you want to discuss things that span longer than a comments block.  Stop by when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab